# ionic slider - there is a way to change interval dynamiclly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to change the interval according to the input of the user:

```
                <div class="item range range-positive">
                    speed :
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-speedometer-outline"></i>
                    <input ng-model="learnSpeed" type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="20000" value="2000">
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-speedometer"></i>
                </div>



                <ion-slide-box does-continue="true"
                               auto-play="true"
                               slide-interval="{{learnSpeed}}"
                               on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="word in allWords" >
                        <div class="box center"
                             ng-class="getRandomColor(word.name)">
                            <h1>{{word.name}}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </ion-slide>
                </ion-slide-box>
</div>
```

what happen now is that the
 `slide-interval="{{learnSpeed}}"`  get the speed from the input, but the slider not run with this interval.

there is a way to do it?

EDIT:

when I add this code to the controller, it's not working as well :

```
controller('learnCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
        $scope.$watch('learnSpeed', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('oldValue=' + oldValue);
            console.log('newValue=' + newValue);
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        });
});
```

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may have to do from your controller is call `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();` from your controller when the user changes the value of the interval.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: Thanks for the update. How are you triggering the event?

Comment: I don't understand..I have input field with model : learnSpeed.
now in the controller I have watch on this variable.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$scope.learnSpeed` to the `newValue`?